# Update an element with Redux Toolkit reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Trying to update an array of chats. What i'm trying to update is messages from an specific
chat from the array. So i receive the msg to add and the chat id in the reducer.

```
updateChatData: (state, action: PayloadAction<Object>) => {
    const { chatId, msgToPush } = action.payload;
    const foundChat = current(state.chats.find((chat) => chat.chatId === msg.chatId));      
}
```

So if i add current foundHcat exists but when i try to push to the foundChat messages array i get an error saying it is only read property.
And using only:

```
const foundChat = state.chats.find((chat) => chat.chatId === msg.chatId)
```

i get undefined. Any idea why ?

```
// chat object structure
{
    chatId: 1,
    messages: [{...}],
}
```

Entire chatSlice:

```
const initialState: ChatsState = {
  chats: [],
  isAllowedExpand: true
};

export const chatsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'chats',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setChatsData: (state, action: PayloadAction<Array<Chat>>) => {
      state.chats = action.payload;
    },
    setIsAllowedExpand: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.isAllowedExpand = action.payload;
    },
    updateChatData: (state, action: PayloadAction<Object>) => {
      const { msg, msgEntry } = action.payload;
      const foundTask = current(state.chats.find((chat) => chat.chatId === msg.chatId));

    }
  }
})
```

This is all chatSlice actions.

And this is the socket where the action is called:

```
socket.on('chats', (msg) => {
        if (
          msg.action === 'ReceivedNewMessage' ||
          msg.action === 'SentNewMessage' ||
          msg.action === 'delete' ||
          msg.action === 'create'
        ) {

          dispatch(updateChatData({msg, msgEntry}))
          setMsgEntry('')
        }
      });
```

Comment: Please, give the context code part. 
What current function does?
Probability seems to be reference error because find will return a reference you need pass a copy but try give more code

Comment: @FábioRibeirodeCarvalho added chatSlice, do you need anything else ?

Comment: `Array.prototype.find` returns `undefined` when no element matches by the predicate function. Please include a complete [mcve] so we can see everything the code does and references. For example, what is `current`? What are the values of `state.chats` and `msg`? What are you trying to do after a match is found?

Comment: @Gonzalo yes, please. Put the code when you are doing this: "current foundHcat exists but when I try to push to the foundChat messages array ". push to the array and what is the current function does